# p: rowExpansion repeats the component each time the expansion arrow is pressed

Tags: java, primefaces, primeng-datatable, primefaces-extensions

Pressing the arrow to expand the row repeats the element several times.

```
         <p:dataTable id="#{cc.attrs.dataTableId}"
                     value="#{cc.attrs.lazyDataModel}" var="value" lazy="#{cc.attrs.isLazy}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                     scrollable="true" tableStyle="width:100%" rowKey="#{solicitud.id}"
                     paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30" rows="10">
            <p:column style="width:20px">
                <p:rowToggler/>
            </p:column>
            <!-- table content -->
            <p:rowExpansion >
                <p:dataTable value="#{value.items}" var="items" tableStyle="width:100%"
                             emptyMessage="#{i18n.label_datatable_noregistros}" >
                    <!--subtable content-->
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:rowExpansion>
        </p:dataTable>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2XvZ.png)

Comment: Just my two cents I have had issues trying to use the p:datatable as a Composite Component.  Can you try it without it being inside a composite component first?

Comment: every time I press the expansion arrow a new component is added, as shown in the image